Why does something being conditioned mean that it has to be impermanent? If something arose in the past, why would it mean that it can cease?

“‘All conditioned things are impermanent’ — when one sees this with wisdom, one turns away from suffering.” -The Buddha, from Dhammapada, verse 277


“Whatever has the nature of arising, all of it has the nature of ceasing.” -The Buddha, from Kimsuka Sutta

But why does something being conditioned mean that it has to be impermanent?
And why does something having arisen mean that it has the "nature" of ceasing?
Most scientists believe that this localized spacetime manifold in its current state had an origin 13.8 billion years ago. The current consensus among the scientific community regarding the future of this localized spacetime manifold is that it will simply continue to expand forever if we are to believe the current cosmological data.
I wrote that as an example, but likewise, I can give other examples. Its not at all clear to me as to why something having arisen means that it can cease, and its not at all clear to me as to why something being conditioned means that it is impermanent. Of course, one could retort and say that the contents of the universe might change or that in this moment, that particle will be in a different position, but that means largely nothing because there is a difference between the microscopic and macroscopic things we observe from our point of view, which is why we distinguish between something like classical mechanics and quantum mechanics. Even with this, many, e.g. Neoplatonists, would contest this notion and say that the Universal Intellect as they conceptualize it is conditioned and created as well as composite, but never changes and is eternal.
All in all, its not at all clear to me what proof is given for the idea that all conditioned things are impermanent, and that whatever has the nature of arising, all of it has the nature of ceasing. Any help on explaining this would be appreciated.

The eventual fate of the universe is uncertain due to our incomplete understandings. One is the understanding of how gravity works. We don't have a complete picture. We don't know what happens or how gravity behaves at the moment of the Big Bang or inside a singularity like a black hole or at the level of atoms and molecules. Truth is we also don't know what causes gravity. Is it particles called gravitons or gravitational waves? Both had not been directly detected or observed.

The second problem is we don't know what exactly is the universe composed of. Again, we only know approximately 5% with a degree of certainty while the rest is embarrassingly termed as dark energy and dark matter. Therefore, your example is not really a good one.

@Desmon Its just the first thing that came to my mind. I can come up with other examples. Don't get overly caught up with it. I wanted to demonstrate that on a rational apriori level, there is nothing particularly irrational with the idea of something being conditioned and arising and yet eternal/not being able to cease.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_unanswerable_questions

The mistranslated phrase below is not about impermanence (anicca).

yaṁ kiñci samudayadhammaṁ sabbaṁ taṁ nirodhadhamman
“Whatever has the nature of arising, all of it has the nature of ceasing.”
The Buddha, from Dhammacakkappavattana Sutta

The word 'samudaya' ('arising') is defined in SN 22.5, as follows:

And what is the origin (arising) of form, feeling, perception, choices
and consciousness?
Ko ca, bhikkhave, rūpassa samudayo, ko vedanāya samudayo, ko saññāya
samudayo, ko saṅkhārānaṁ samudayo, ko viññāṇassa samudayo?
It’s when a mendicant approves, welcomes and keeps clinging.
Idha, bhikkhave, bhikkhu abhinandati abhivadati ajjhosāya tiṭṭhati.
SN 22.5

Therefore, the original quote (from the Buddha's first sermon) says that which arises due to craving & attachment is all subject to cessation (when the Noble Eightfold Path is engaged).
This is not the same as 'impermanence'. While impermanence can indicate 'disappearance', impermanence can also indicate mere 'change'.
Therefore, if the physical universe keeps expanding, this may not be cessation but it is certainly impermanence. Expansion is impermanence. Impermanence is not always cessation.
For example, on earth, there is something called 'the ocean'. Whether the ocean has a water volume of 1,335,000,000 cubic kilometers or otherwise 1,400,000,000 cubic kilometers, it remains 'the ocean'. The ocean has not yet 'ceased'. Therefore the impermanence of the ocean's volume of water does not necessarily indicate the cessation of the ocean.
It follows once the component phenomena have substantially moved out of their positions or themselves have changed (them being transient arrangements of other phenomena and so on ad infinitum), the universe as 'the universe' remains itself; even though the universe has been subject to impermanence or change.

+1 Perfect answer.

alwase, perfect.

A conditioned thing depends on two or more supporting conditions, like a house of cards, and every phenomenon that exists is conditioned. Without the supports in place, it collapses. "When this is, that is. When this ceases, that ceases." Nothing exists in a vacuum; everything depends on supporting conditions, from outside itself, and those conditions in turn depend on other conditions, and so on, down to the tiniest fragment or fractal.
Anything that arises/is born, not only can cease/die, it has to cease. Finite causes cannot have infinite effects. What goes up must come down.

As Andriy Volkov pointed out, the Buddhist perspective sees reality as a continous process, not as things existing.  The three marks of existence (dukkha, anica, anatta) refer to how you experience the world.
The definition of a process is ongoing change, something that develops over time.  Therefore (from a Buddhist perspective) the only valid way to not having something to cease is to stop time.
Some concepts (like you gave with the universe coming into existence) are simply beyong the scope of this.  You could make a similar argument about abstract ideas like math. Does math cease to exist if the last mathematically trained person in the universe perishes?
If you focus on your experience, it becomes obvious that all phenomena eventually cease (because they will be replaced by other phenomana).  For example right now you are reading this post I wrote. Eventually you'll be done reading and something else will happen (because your reality is an ongoing process).
There is only ever ONE experience at a time, so if you would become aware of a phenomena and this wouldn't cease, the same as above would apply- time would have to stop, and without time, the concept of experiencing something doesn't make sense.
I understand if this answer might be unsatisfactory to you, because it doesn't really explain your question.
But allow me a few more words on this:
The goal of Buddhist philosophy is to end suffering. We are suffering because our beliefs are in conflict with reality. We would be liberated if you could see as they really are (shattering ignorance).
You might be tempted to get there by (intellectually, pariyatti) understanding the teachings of the Buddha (for example the three marks of existence).
But the only way to fully liberate you (and also to fully understand these) is by experience (paṭipatti).
For example when watching phenomena come and go as part of insight meditation, the three marks of existence will be understood experientially and this has a different effect.
Think of it as trying to learn everything about what it is like to give birth. You might be able to read everything, including what it feels in the body and what it does emotionally.
You might be even able to talk to someone else and trick them into thinking that you really experienced giving birth.
But all this is still intellectual knowledge and not experiential knowledge. You will only ever be able to understand what it means to give birth once you have experienced it yourself.
So, if you are simply interested in dissecting Buddhism out of philosophical curiosity (which is fine), then there is no satisfactory answer to your question that tells you anything useful (similar to the answer to the question what it really is like to be enlightened).
On the other hand, if you are pondering these questions because you have a desire to be liberated from suffering, then the answer to your question will not liberate you, but attempting to actually experience anicca will (for example by meditation dilligently).

"Sabbe saṅkhārā aniccā" seems to mean that all saṅkhārā are fallible. Can we realize this? What are these saṅkhārā delivered with a seemingly void warranty? Do we know them?
"yaṁ kiñci samudayadhammaṁ sabbaṁ taṁ nirodhadhamman" seems to mean that if it can emanate, it can be cleared out. Can we realize this too? Do we know the clearing out of something?

I suppose the Buddhist notion of phenomena made of causes-and-conditions differs from the mainstream understanding of cause-and-effect causality.
The typical, simplistic, materialistic idea of causality resembles the game of billiard - you push a ball, it pushes another ball. The first ball passing kinetic energy to the second ball is "the cause".
Note how the focus is (usually) on material objects, with energy and other dynamic qualities (temperature, electric charge) considered their properties.
In Buddhism, there's no obsession with entities or objects. Instead, a conditioned phenomenon is defined as something that is "made of" its causes and conditions. A phenomenon is a bundle of a number of other phenomena with its quality and behavior emerging from the mutual action of the elements of the bundle. The phenomenon is considered existing (or, more accurately, "can be identified" or "can be delineated" - because identifying and delineating phenomena is an act of an observer) for as long as the elements comprising the bundle are in more or less the same functional configuration. Once the component phenomena have substantially moved out of their positions or themselves have changed (them being transient arrangements of other phenomena and so on ad infinitum), the original phenomenon is no longer itself.
In our ball example, the phenomenon is "a rolling ball" made of components such as mass, momentum, and environment (here analyzed coarsely). The phenomenon stays more or less the same self for as long as its components don't change - and obviously the environment is the one that keeps on changing over time, with the ball encountering micro obstacles, these obstacles nibble on the momentum component, momentum gets smaller and smaller, and eventually the rolling ball phenomenon ceases and from its ashes the resting ball phenomenon is born.
Here's your answer, conditioned phenomena are impermanent, because the conditions they are made of are themselves conditioned phenomena (I'm sorry here I must point out that a distinct phenomenon is a simplification, in real life things blend into each other without clean boundaries, both spacial and temporal, and yet phenomena can be roughly delineated) and this entire infinite graph of derived phenomena keeps on shifting continuously, with no derived phenomenon immune to eventual cessation.

" this entire infinite graph of derived phenomena keeps on shifting continuously" How do you know this? Why can't there be a portion of this graph which stays basically eternal, interacting with other points of the graph via only a single, persistent connection?

You keep separating phenomena from their interactions but in Buddhism, phenomena are interactions. There's no such thing as static phenomenon interacting with a non-static phenomenon. In that case what you call static phenomenon would be in part defined by its interaction, making it non-static on that side.

"There's no such thing as static phenomenon interacting with a non-static phenomenon" Some Neoplatonists would contest this & say that the Universal Intellect is static but is eternally interacting with and producing the Universal Soul, which is dynamic and exists within perpetuity.  " In that case what you call static phenomenon would be in part defined by its interaction, making it non-static on that side" I guess if u think abt it that way, then its true. But that still doesn't mean that it can CEASE to exist or sufficiently change to be something unrecognizable. So question still remains.

Well, according to Buddhism, every conditioned/derived phenomenon is a temporary bundle of its constituents. If it had a point when its components came together to form it, it will have a point where they will drift apart. You are free to accept this or deny but this is the Buddhist answer.
